I can't unscrew the rotor bolts
I have a torx screwdriver but it wasn't meant for bike maintenance use. Actually I had bought it to unscrew the bolts of my owen. However, it sits firmly on the bolts of the rotor but can't unscrew them. Maybe the bolts are too tight and I don't apply enough force but a friend of mine has told me that the screwdriver tip should have a circular shape to match the little holes on the bolts. Mine is flat. Is this the reason I can't unscrew the bolts?
Here are the photos of the screwdriver and bolts:



Could you perhaps also include the photo of the bolts? Or link to an image that shows the same bolts? Does the torx head look like this?

No, they don't have a notch inside. I've added the photo.

That looks like a regular torx indeed, but with some corrosive decoration. In theory it should work with a regular torx screwdriver. Perhaps you can clamp the screwdriver, place the screw on it and use the wheel as leverage?

First of all (before you damage the heads) I’d put some WD40 or other penetrating oil on those corroded screws and let it soak for a few hours. I’d get an L-shaped Torx key like your typical hex key. It will provide much more leverage than that screwdriver.

@Michael And just as an addendum for OP, if you (OP) do decide to use penetrating oil on these bolts, make sure to clean it off real good afterwards so that you don't contaminate your brakes.

Rotor bolts usually have threadlocker on them (if you buy new brakes, you'll see it as blue stuff on the screws).  You need more torque than a screwdriver style tool (unless you can get a good grip and really get your whole arm into it).
A threadlocked bolt will start with a jerk and a snapping sound, then be much easier (though still not loose).  A rusted bolt  may also start suddenly, but won't ease as much.
